# Update message submitted via incoming webhook in slack.com API

Tags: slack

I was hoping to update the message body posted via incoming webhook to the Slack API for my org. I was looking at the [API doc for incoming-webhooks](https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks) and it shows how to post, but at time of writing, that pages gives no directives for updating existing messages.

Can the web hook posting be combined with the [chat.update functionality](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.update)?

How can a message posted via a webhook be identified and updated?

Comment: APIs are really in the domain of programming. I don't think this question is on-topic here.

Comment: I'm losing motivation to find the right staxex site, I promise you. Seems like there is always one person who doesn't like where I posted any question. I'd rather it be wherever a moderate decides to put it. Feel absolutely free to flag and suggest where it should go. :)

Answer (score 3):

Web hook posting can indeed be combined with chat.update functionality. I'll walk you through it below.

First use the `channels.list` API method to determine the encoded channel id which you want to update messages in. Once you have the channel id call the `channels.history` method to list messages to this channel. From this response you'll be able to identify messages from incoming webhooks via the `bot_id` field in the message and also via the `username` field. Record the ts id of the messages you want to update.

You are now ready to call the `chat.update` method using the ts id and channel id for the messages you would like to update.

All the API methods listed above are described in detail on the [Slack API methods page](https://api.dev.slack.com/methods). Reputation limits unfortunately prevent me from directly linking to the API method pages.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Reading over this, It sounds like it needs about three individual api calls to do in entirety; not including the original to post the webhook message. Would there be any reason a high volume system (or any other) should prefer to use regular `chat.postMessage` So that the message can be updated by a single following api call? (This is really a concern about rate limiting)

Comment: You can likely cache the channel id so you could probably get away with making just two calls each time.

To answer your question though; yes I think a high volume system that anticipates frequently needed to update messages could benefit from using `chat.postMessage`. If you call `chat.postMessage` you get all the information you need to make a later call to `chat.update` in the response.

Comment: This fails with the `cant_update_message` error.